# Não estou conseguindo mostrar minha feed do instagram

Tags: javascript, html

Boa tarde amigos, não entendo o porque da minha página não mostrar minha feed do instagram, alguém pode me ajudar?

Este é o erro apresentado: Instagram: The access_token provided is invalid.

#### Código em JS

```
$(function() {

    //Set up instafeed
    var feed = new Instafeed({
        clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        target: 'instafeed',
        get: 'tagged',
        tagName: 'photographyportfolio',
        links: true,
        limit: 8,
        sortBy: 'most-recent',
        resolution: 'standard_resolution',
        template: '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><div class="photo-box"><div class="image-wrap"><a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}"></a><div class="likes">{{likes}} Likes</div></div><div class="description">{{caption}}<div class="date">{{model.date}}</div></div></div></div>'
    });
    feed.run();

});
```

#### Código HTML

```
<div class="instagram-content">
    <h3>Latest Photos</h3>
    <div class="row photos-wrap">
    <!-- Instafeed target div -->
    <div id="instafeed"></div>
    <!-- The following HTML will be our template inside instafeed -->
    <!-- <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="photo-box">
            <div class="image-wrap">
                <img src="images/test_img.jpg">
                <div class="likes">309 Likes</div>
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                Fantastic Architecture #architecture #testing
                <div class="date">September 16, 2014</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> -->

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Algum erro na consola?

Comment: nenhum, peguei esse exemplo: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/pt/tutorials/building-an-instagram-based-portfolio-with-bootstrap--cms-22243  -  coloquei minha id e não consegui visualizar.

Comment: Como está o head do seu html ?

Comment: Viste na aba de "network" das dev-tools o pedido ajax a sair? o que dá lá?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolvendo apenas uma parte, pois não quero mostrar por #hashtag e sim por usuário:

```
$(function() {

//Set up instafeed
  var userFeed = new Instafeed({
  get: 'tagged',
  target: 'instafeed',
  clientId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  accessToken: 'XxxXXxxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxxxxxxxxx',
  tagName: 'maceio',
  links: true,
  limit: 8,
  sortBy: 'most-recent',
  resolution: 'standard_resolution',
  template: '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><div class="photo-box"><div class="image-wrap"><a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}"></a><div class="likes">{{likes}} Likes</div></div><div class="description">{{caption}}<div class="date">{{model.date}}</div></div></div></div>'
});
userFeed.run();
});
```